# What is the information plane theorem for an autoencoder neural network?

Tags: neural-networks, information-theory, autoencoders, mutual-information

Slide 8 (about 19 minutes into the video) of the [*Stanford Seminar - Information Theory of Deep Learning, Naftali Tishby*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XL07WEc2TRI) has the following (rather informally stated) theorem.

> **Theorem (Information Plane)** For large typical $\mathbf{X}$, the sample complexity of a DNN is completely determined by the encoder mutual information $\mathbf{I(X;T)}$, of the last hidden layer; the accuracy (generalization error) is determined by the decoder information, $\mathbf{I(T;Y)}$, of the last hidden layers.

I am having difficulty following what is meant by "the sample complexity is completely determined". What is the precise statement of this theorem?

Comment: There is an "encoder" and a "decoder".  The information bottleneck is at the end of the encoder and front of the decoder.  The space that the decoder reads from is the bottleneck.  If the information cannot pass through the bottleneck, then it cannot get to the decoder, and it cannot be decoded.  That means that the bottleneck defines the maximum performance (whatever that means) of the whole system.

Comment: Could you provide some context? What are $\mathbf X, \mathbf Y,$ and $\mathbf T$?

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is to apply information theoratic principles to undertand the flow of information between layers. There are two important metrics in this regard.

1. The entropy
2. The Mutual information between the layers

So the Information bottleneck principle creates an information plane with x axis capturing the mutual information between X and Z (encoder) whereas Y  axis captures Mutual Information between Z and Y (Decoder). The basic finding based on experiments is that during the initial stages of training the Mutual information on both axis increases but after a certain point (called the bottleneck), the MI between X and Z starts to get less. This is called the compression phase. Intuitively this means that Z starts to only remember meaningful information from X and forget the rest.

Hope this helps